# how to install a library with a different name in waf build system?

Tags: c++, python, waf

I want to build a library with waf, but install it under a different name than the target name. It seems you can do

```
bld.shlib(..., install_path='${PREFIX}/lib')
```

but I need to be able to do something like:

```
bld.shlib(..., install_as='${PREFIX}/lib/xyz')
```

Also, bld.install_as() wont work, as it doesn't seem to accept a task as a target, and I can't figure out how to turn a task into a node representing the target, so the following doesnt work either:

```
tgt = bld.shlib(...)
bld.install_as('foo', tgt)
```

Or alternatively, I need to be able to disable the "lib" prefix that is automatically added to library names, but only for this one library - not for all them during the build, e.g. something like:

```
bld.shlib(..., libprefix='', install_path="${PREFIX}/lib/")
```

I know you can set shlib_PATTERN as well, but that seems to affect all libraries under the current environment. We have a pretty complicated build that uses a lot of different environments for building debug/release concurrently, so just cloning the current environment and changing the flag doesnt work either, because it clones the default environment, not the one the target will eventually be built under (because we clone the targets for each environment during build time).

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
hello_lib = bld.shlib(
       includes='/usr/include/python',
       source='a.cpp',
       target='hello',
       uselib='BOOST_PYTHON',
       vnum='0.0.1')
hello_lib.env.cxxshlib_PATTERN = '%s.so'
```

This code changes naming pattern for only one task.

Answer (score 1):

There are two keyword arguments you can use: "name" and "target". "target" is the name of the file create while Name is the name of the target when using the "--target" argument. Confusing, but here is an example:

```
bld(features=['cxx','cxxshlib'],
    source=src,
    includes=inc,
    target='OutputName',
    name='NameOfTarget',
    use=libs,
    install_path='${PREFIX}/lib/MyLibs
    )
```

```
waf configure build install --target=NameOfTarget --prefix=/home/Brian
```

This creates a shared library "libOutputName.so" and installs it to /home/Brian/lib/MyLib